# Select option in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having trouble with select options. I need to select the Glasstypes and its sub-types according to GlassTypes and glass-thickness according to sub-types.
My Json is 
   `glass:[
     "glassTypeOne":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "subTypeName":"subTypeOneOne",
        "thickness":[
          {
            "name":"4mm",
          },{
            "name":"5mm",
          },{
            "name":"8mm",
          }
        ]
       },{
        "id":2,
        "subTypeName":"subTypeOneTwo",
        "thickness":[
          {
            "name":"4mm",
          },{
            "name":"5mm",
          },{
            "name":"6mm",
          },{
            "name":"8mm",
          }
        ]
       }
      ],
      "glassTypeTwo":[
       {
        "id":1,
        "subTypeName":"subTypeTwoOne",
        "thickness":[
          {
            "name":"4mm",
          },{
            "name":"5mm",
          },{
            "name":"6mm",
          },{
            "name":"8mm",
          }
        ]
       },{
        "id":2,
        "subTypeName":"subTypeTwoTwo",
        "thickness":[
          {
            "name":"4mm",
          },{
            "name":"5mm",
          },{
            "name":"6mm",
          },{
            "name":"8mm",
          }
        ]
       }
      ]
     ]`
First select-type input select the Type and another select populates the subselect and another select populates the thickness.
Any one help or give slight hint of doing it.in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Please run code snippet to see it in action (hope this is what you were looking for?!)

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    function HomeController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.glassTypes = [{
                name: "One",
                details: [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "subTypeName": "subTypeOneOne",
                        "thickness": [
                            {
                                "name": "4mm",
                            }, {
                                "name": "5mm",
                            }, {
                                "name": "8mm",
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id": 2,
                        "subTypeName": "subTypeOneTwo",
                        "thickness": [
                            {
                                "name": "4mm",
                            }, {
                                "name": "5mm",
                            }, {
                                "name": "6mm",
                            }, {
                                "name": "8mm",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                    name: "Two",
                    details: [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "subTypeName": "subTypeTwoOne",
                            "thickness": [
                                {
                                    "name": "4mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "5mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "6mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "8mm",
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            "id": 2,
                            "subTypeName": "subTypeTwoTwo",
                            "thickness": [
                                {
                                    "name": "4mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "5mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "6mm",
                                }, {
                                    "name": "8mm",
                                }
                            ]
                        }]
            }];
    }

    app.controller("HomeController", [HomeController]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular JS App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">

            <select class="form-control" ng-model="homeCtrl.glass" ng-options="glass.name for glass in homeCtrl.glassTypes"></select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="homeCtrl.subglass" ng-options="subglass.subTypeName for subglass in homeCtrl.glass.details"></select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="homeCtrl.thickness" ng-options="thickness.name for thickness in homeCtrl.subglass.thickness"></select>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had to change your json to it work. Isn't this what you were looking for?!